# Pandas.series str extract does not get string of one digit

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I need to extract the digit from a column of string. But str.extract(\d) does not work for string of only numeric.

```
df['extract'] = df['original'].str.extract('(\d+)')
```

Please see the dataframe as dictionary:

```
{'original': {0: 'NO RATING',
  1: 4,
  2: '3-',
  3: 3,
  4: '4-',
  5: '2-',
  6: '2+',
  7: '4+',
  8: '5-',
  9: 5,
  10: '5+',
  11: 2,
  12: '3+',
  13: '6+',
  14: '6-',
  15: 6,
  16: 7},
 'extract': {0: nan,
  1: nan,
  2: '3',
  3: nan,
  4: '4',
  5: '2',
  6: '2',
  7: '4',
  8: '5',
  9: nan,
  10: '5',
  11: nan,
  12: '3',
  13: '6',
  14: '6',
  15: nan,
  16: nan}}
```

df is a pd dataframe with 2 columns, df['orginal'] contains values like 2+, 2-,2, 3-,3, 3+, NO RATING.

the code works generates new column df['extract'], which is correct for values like 2-(gives 2), 3+(gives 3), NO RATING(gives NaN). But it's wrong for values like 2(gives NaN, but I'm expecting 2) and 3(gives NaN, but I'm expecting 3).

[my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNd9x.png)

Comment: Can you post your `df.to_dict()` where `df` is the small `df` from the screeshot?

Comment: Your code works perfectly in my case, you need to change the regex that you are using from `(\d)` to `(\d+)` to handle number with more than one digit. And of course, the negative sign will be neglected

Comment: better edit the original post than post as a comment. Original posts can always be edited, comments only for 5 minutes

Comment: @Anwarvic , can you please show me your result? Thank you. I definitely tried and searched before I post the question. If you can show me how this works it will be great. But please don't just say like your code works in my case and vote negative. I ask this question because I don't understand why str extract acts like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make sure you have all strings before using `extract`

```
df['extract'] = df['original'].astype(str).str.extract('(\d+)')
```

Comment: This works!! Thank you I got why it was not working. I thought a column only has one datatype which is string..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is some of the values are integers while some are string. Although str.extract is not getting an error, it is not extracting the correct values if it is an integer. You can use lambda and findall functions to handle this case. Then also add an optional operator (+) to get more digits in case value is > 9.

```
df['extract'] = df['original'].map(lambda x: re.findall('(\d+)', str(x))) \
                           .map(lambda i: i[0] if len(i)>0 else None)
```

Result:

```
   original extract
0   5         5
1   13+      13
```

Comment: Mark it as correct answer if you are satisfied. thanks.

Comment: could you please also address 'NO RATING' case? this gives error

Comment: Thank you as well! This works perfectly. It just does not allow 2 selected answers.